# Sitecore - ECM: How to redirect to a Sitecore page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I have got an issue with link inside my newsletter generated via ECM Module of Sitecore.

I have two different links which will compose my newsletter.
One is to redirect the user to the newsletter Online page and the other one is Read More link per article.

How can I define the correct link to the newsletter sent to the user ? In the newsletter, there is a field $fullname$, is it possible to see the correct value ?

Each article will have a Read More linl. How can I redirect the user to the page article with the correct text ? Which information do I need to send ? which configuration do I need to do in the template ?
Do you have any example on how to redirect the user to web site pages ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

First: I forgot to publish some Items and the web site. When we are not in the Sitecore Desktop, to navigate to the solution, we should publish the web site (and not forget the item :))

Second: The language -> My newsletter should be shown in a the User language. I had to change a parameter in the web.config: The parameter "LanguageEmbedding=asNeeded should be changed by Always.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but if you are looking to send out email newsletters with list of articles and link back to them, then in your user control, you must iterate over the collection of articles and user sitecore API Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl() to paint the link on the rendered document.

Comment: I made something like that (don't know if it's correct). An article is based on a Template. Each article is defined with Sitecore. I have created an aspx page for the article. In the aspx page, I made a reference to the Field with sc:FieldRendered or sc:Image. The aspx page has been linked to the StandardValue of the Item Template (Configuration -> Details -> Edit -> Layout = Article.aspx). In the template, I have defined a field "Link" type General Link. the value is the content item itself. Is that make sence ?

Comment: Sorry, not via Configuration. But via Presentation -> Details -> Controls Edit -> Layout

Comment: That's working fine during the test phase (using the test button) once i'm sending for real the newsletter (using the Dispatch button) it's not working at all. What do you mean by: "You must iterate over the collection of articles" ?